A good tutorial on how to use GRIB/GRIB2 in Wolfram?
I am totally unable to find a useful example of how to work with GRIB/GRIB2 files on top of maps in Wolfram. For example:
Source File: https://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/SL.us008001/ST.opnl/DF.gr2/DC.ndfd/AR.oceanic/VP.004-007/ds.wspd.bin
This has to be explicitly Imported as "GRIB". I get that part. :-)
How would I plot this on top of a map?

The Mathematica documentation indicates that a GRIB file should have an extension of either .grb or .grib Is the file available with either of those extensions? Have you tried just changing the extension?

I'm afraid you misunderstood the question. It imports fine as long as specify "GRIB" in the Import command. The question is whether anyone has a tutorial for how to actually use these files (i.e., lay a weather radar GRIB on top of a map).
